# Map app unxpectedly get close show Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, google-play-services, android-maps-v2

I am creating the native map using android google map api v2 
i just show the procedure from the link http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/
i tried so far some of the error has been solved but still map is not rendering it shows the following  error[image]

and here is whole code trace..........................................

```
.........................................androidmanifest.xml..............................
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.map"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" >
    </permission>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.map.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAmFQLVogHnMayejnRjtwqfJ7rFckQ4KJ0" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
............................mainactivity.java................................
package com.example.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initializeMap();

        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

        double latitude = 17.385044;
        double longitude = 78.486671;

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            double[] randomLocation=createRandLocation(latitude,
                    longitude);

            MarkerOptions markerOptions=new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(randomLocation[0], randomLocation[1])).title("hello bam bam"+i);
            Log.e("Random", "> " + randomLocation[0] + ", "
                    + randomLocation[1]);

            // changing marker color
            if (i == 0)
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));
            if (i == 1)
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE));
            if (i == 2)
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
            if (i == 3)
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
            if (i == 4)
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
            if (i == 5)
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE));
            if (i == 6)
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));
            if (i == 7)
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE));
            if (i == 8)
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_VIOLET));
            if (i == 9)
                markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW));

            googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

            // Move the camera to last position with a zoom level
            if (i == 9) {
                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(randomLocation[0],
                                randomLocation[1])).zoom(15).build();
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        }

        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        initializeMap();
    }
    private void initializeMap(){
        if (googleMap==null){
            googleMap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            if(googleMap==null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "brother map is not renedering please do somethingh",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
    private double[] createRandLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {

        return new double[] { latitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                longitude + ((Math.random() - 0.5) / 500),
                150 + ((Math.random() - 0.5) * 10) };
    }



}
...................................activity_main.xml.............................
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" 
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I build this using target 4.2.2 google api and how to show the google map on android emulator i am developing the app using the ADT
already imported the google play services lib  and all necessary jar 
anyone please do tell me where i am stuck why map is not showing on emulator 
i am newbie at android

thank you in advance...

[image]

Comment: Post your java code. It's to do with something in your onCreate method.

Comment: hey i have already post the whole code

Comment: Your error is on line 20

Comment: try first enabling the compass  googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true); and then
        googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

Comment: @mdlc i ll chk hope it will work for me..is we can use google map v2 in android

Comment: @Elenasys thank u for helping but it didn't work for me it will show the same error please tell me what more i can do render the map

Comment: Whats in MainActivity line 29=

Comment: @Elenasys   compass googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true)

Comment: @Elenasys i did it but the problem still persist

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to extend your activity from main class **Activity** and for MapFragment you need to import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.

That might help you.

Comment: i have already included in my code still it is showing the issue

Answer (score 0):

**Only The following Code is enough to open map :-
Now you can use map object to animate camera and using markers.**

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/map"
          android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

========================Java File=================

```
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();


  Hope,this will solve your problem .
```